# Changing Window XP Network configuration (IP Address, Subnet, Default GW etc) in CMD

Tags: windows, networking, windows-xp, netsh

I'm not able to permanently replace my Ip addresses using NETSH.
I've tried all possible options but nothing. when I reboot the computer I get my old IPs.

I'm this was done before...

any idea?
Thanks!!
E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which OS?  The following will work on Vista onwards:

```
netsh int ipv4 set address "Local Area Network" static <IP address> <subnet mask> <gateway> <metric>
```

eg.

```
netsh int ipv4 set address "Local Area Network" static 192.168.1.100 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1 1
```

You may need to replace "Local Area Network" with whatever the friendly name for the interface is, which you can check with `ipconfig /all`.

Replace `ipv4` with `ip` for XP/2000/2003.

Comment: Windows XP OS machine

Comment: @EladDotan: IIRC, for XP all you need to do is replace `ipv4` with `ip` for this particular command.